# How to pass ngModel for Checkbox-Group using ControlValueAccessor to parent Component?

Tags: angular, controlvalueaccessor

I'am using a custom component for multiCheckbox with `ControlValueAccessor`.

**`checkbox.component.ts`**:

```
import {
    Component,
    OnInit,
    forwardRef,
    Input,
    ViewChild,
    ElementRef,
    Output,
    EventEmitter
} from "@angular/core";
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
    selector: "app-checkbox",
    templateUrl: "./checkbox.component.html",
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => CheckboxComponent),
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class CheckboxComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
    isChecked = false;
    public userStatus = [
                {name: 'user1', checked: true},
                {name: 'user2', checked: false},
                {name: 'user3', checked: false}
    ]

    propagateChange = (_: any) => {};
    onTouchedCallback = () => {};

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    writeValue(value: any) {
        this.checked = value;
    }

    submit($event: Event) {
        console.log(this.userStatus);
    }

    registerOnChange(func: any) {
        this.propagateChange = func;
    }
    registerOnTouched(func: any) {
        this.onTouchedCallback = func;
    }
}
```

**`checkbox.component.html`**:

```
<section class="checkbox-section" *ngFor="let opt of userStatus">
    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="opt.checked" name="{{opt.name}}">{{ opt.name }}</mat-checkbox>
    <br>
    CheckBox Name {{ opt.name }}
 </section>

<br><br>
{{userStatus | json}}
```

Till that point it works fine. But the issue is that I can't pass the `ngModel` to parent component where the `checkboxes` are bounded.

`**parent.component.html**`:

```
<app-checkbox [name]="'CheckBoxRoles'" [ngModel]="name"></app-checkbox>
```

I can't track the `ngModel` of the of all three checkboxes and pass them to one array as name/status. In `checkbox.component.html` itself is working fine, but not in the parent.

Any idea where I'am going wrong? P.S. I don't want to use: `formGroup` option.